# Gcc how to resolve a virtual method into a resolved normal method

Tags: c++, virtual

Having

- A method pointer (eventually virtual)
- The type of a class

I need to convert the virtual call to a non-virtual call. So the virtual pointer into a resolved pointer.

The question is:  how do I do that e.g. in GCC (in case there isn't a standard provided method). I wouldn't like to use hacks as those described below, but just some call hidden somewhere into the included files.

In order to clarify the subject I will explain what I have seen up to now while debugging the assembly code compiled by GCC.
I have seen that a generic method pointer holds two data:

- a "pointer" to the method
- an offset to add eventually to the class instance starting address

The offset is used when multiple inheritance is involved and for methods of the second and further parent class that if applied to their objects would have their data at different starting points.

The "pointer" to the method is as follows:

1. if the "pointer" is even it is interpreted as a normal (non virtual) function pointer.
2. If the "pointer" is odd then 1 should be subtracted and the remaining value should be 0 or 4 or 8 or 12 ( supposing a pointer size of 4 bytes).

The previous codification supposes obviously that all normal methods start at even addresses (so the compiler should align them at even addresses).
That offset is the offset into the vtable where the address of the "real" non virtual method pointer may be found.

So one way to do what I request is:

Create a dummy object of the required type, get its address, at the beginning of its data there is the pointer to the vtable, get it.

Get the method pointer, split into method pointer (address or index  and offset. Add the offset to the object address.
Convert via lookup the index (if the method is virtual) into a non virtual method.

The code that implements what described and used to answer another related but slightly different question ([How to get “direct” function pointer to a virtual member function?][1]) follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <cstdint>

struct Animal {
    int weight = 0x11111111;
    virtual int mm() {printf("Animal1 mm\n");return 0x77;};
    virtual int nn() {printf("Animal1 nn\n");return 0x99;};
};
struct Tiger : Animal {
    int weight = 0x22222222, height = 0x33333333;
    virtual int mm() {printf("Tigerxx\n");return 0xCC;}
    virtual int nn() {printf("Tigerxx\n");return 0x99;};
};
typedef int (Animal::*methodPointerT)();

typedef struct {
    void** functionPtr;
    size_t offset;
} MP;

void devirtualize(methodPointerT& mp0,const Animal& a) {
    MP& t = *(MP*)&mp0;
    if ((intptr_t)t.functionPtr & 1) {
        size_t index = (t.functionPtr-(void**)1); // there is obviously a more
        void **vTable = (void**)(*(void**)&a);    // efficient way. Just for clarity!
        t.functionPtr = (void**)vTable[index];
    }
};

int main()
{
    Animal x;Tiger y;
    methodPointerT mp1 = &Animal::nn;

    (x.*mp1)(); (y.*mp1)();

    devirtualize(mp1,x);

    (x.*mp1)(); (y.*mp1)();
}
```

The output will show something like:

```
Animal1 nn
Tigerxx
Animal1 nn
Animal1 nn
```

Comment: It seems like you are asking for `mem_fn` or `bind` or just a lambda. How does [this](http://ideone.com/gmH4gD) not give you what you need?

Comment: The title I gave was misleading and wrong. My specific need is that I have some plain old structs, that have a proprietary field (e.g. a byte) that indicates their type among a small number of types. These different structs, haven't any virtual method but instead these have methods with the same name and function. So these structs have a method indicating their size and other characteristics. How can I be able to iterate over them ( being all of different type ) and still be able to call the common methods ?

Comment: The simple answer is you cannot "iterate over them" C++ is strongly typed, so you will not be able to collect them all into a container without casting them to a `void*` and even then you wouldn't know what class you had. That said it sounds like part of what you're looking for may be a template: `template <typename T> void callMM(T& foo){foo.mm();}`

Comment: To be able to iterate over your structs, you need to implement some kind of type-erasing. I suggest you take a peek at [this presentation](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil) : even though the motive is different, the chosen solution is probably close to what you're after.

Comment: If you feel your title and description could be improved, it's a good idea to edit it, instead of adding explanations in comments. (Oh, and I wouldn't be surprised if your pointer casts resulted in several cases of undefined behavior.)

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig I already corrected it, I should had mentioned that into the comment in order to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Now I'm getting more confused: Your comment says you don't have virtuals. Which way is it? (In case you edit your question again for some purpose, it would be worth adding the observed output and if that is not what you want in some way, also adding the desired result.)